# Как сделать задержку экрана на длительное время(около 10 мин)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Необходимо получить данные из потока сторонней программы, для этого необходимо перейти в режим бездействия.

**ВОПРОС:**

> Как сделать задержку экрана на длительное время(около 10 мин)?

С функцией `sleep()` знаком, но может есть лучше решение для длительной задержки экрана?
Под задержкой подразумеваю состояние, когда программа бездействует.

Comment: Что есть "задержка экрана"?

Comment: дл якаких целей такая длинная задержка?

Comment: @PinkTux скорее всего подрузомеватеся состояние когда программа бездействует

Comment: можете воспользоваться таймером , на какой платформе пишите??

Comment: @Alex.B  на VS 2015.

Comment: @PinkTux состояние когда программа бездействует.

Comment: а для каких целей?? вы консоль хотите задержать после вывода?? или что-то другое??

Comment: Да, для каких целей. Иногда будет оправдано WaitForSingleObject, если без условий то sleep

Comment: @nick_n_a для того чтобы вывести данные из потока другой программы в свою консоль.

Comment: Для этого достаточно использовать *pipe* (или *named pipe*, для windows можно ф-цию с приставкой peek если нужен таймаут). В windows нужна *WaitForSingleObject* , если не использовать *pipe*. Pipe очень хорошее решение, т.к. легко преобразуется на console-stdout или в log-файл.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, `Sleep` - вполне кошерное решение. Еще одно - `sleep` :)

Если на C++ - то можно воспользоваться `sleep_until` и `sleep_for` из `<thread>`.

Comment: А плюсовые слипы не сшибаются сигналами?

Comment: @PinkTux Гм, как-то не озадачивался этим вопросом... А насколько это принципиально? По большому счету сигнал на то и сигнал, чтоб все пробивать...

Comment: Я к тому, что если задержка нужна на точное время, то, может быть, имеет смысл выплюнуть `alarm()`. После чего уже начать отдыхать, проверяя - не пора ли проснуться? А обработчик `SIGALRM` будет проверять текущее время и, если сигнал пришёл раньше - добивать новыми `alarm()` на остатки времени. Если всё, то прерывать отдых.